# echoing wrong else in php

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I input wrong username, the resulting page gives the second else output. I want the first else to be displayed on the screen if a user types in wrong username and the second else to be displayed when someone tries to go in the login page directly from the url without inputting any name. And yes session_start(); has been declared on top of both the pages.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    $result = $conn->query("select name from students where name = '$username'");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        echo "You are logged in. This is the welcome page. Welcome user: " . $username;
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Invalid username. Try again.";
        }

    $conn->close();
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Come through proper ways.";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Possible issues

In general, you omitted some error management that could lead to unexpected behavior, which breaks the logic of your conditions.

1. You must check `$_POST['username']`, consider possible to receive `$_POST['submit']` without an username (the web is full of surprises). The best way to differentiate missing username and bad username is to check it directly with `isset()` and `empty()` for instance.
2. You must check that the database connection succeeded to avoid exceptions with `conn->connect_errno`.
3. You must check if `$result` evaluates to false which would mean that there is a query error.
4. You may escape `$username` before inserting it into the request, I don't know how *mysqli* manages SQL injections.

## Possible solution

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) ) {

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);

    // check connection
    if ( $conn->connect_errno ){
        die("Data access denied ([".$conn->connect_errno."] ".$conn->connect_error.")");
    }

    $result = $conn->query("select name from students where name = '$username'");

    // check for query errors
    if (!$result) {
        die("Data access denied (invalid query)");
    }

    // ...

} else {
    echo "Come through proper ways.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with following codes

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"] && array_filter($_POST) && $_POST['username']){
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test") or die('Database Connection Failure ' . (($conn->connect_errno) ? $conn->connect_error : ''));
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $result = $conn->query("select name from students where name = '{$username}'");
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        // success
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        echo "You are logged in. This is the welcome page. Welcome user: " . $username;
    }else{
        echo "Invalid username. Try again.";
    }
    $conn->close();
}else{
    echo "Come through proper ways.";
}
```

Comment: Could `extract()` lead to possible injections ? If an user (according to POST mechanism to group fields with same name in a php array) inject the value of  `$_SESSION['username']` ?

Comment: tha'ts why validating with `mysqli_real_escape_string`, check the answer fuly :)

Comment: Yes for  `$_POST['username']` to be exported as `$username` in the local scope. But if a user sends `$_POST['_SESSION']['username']` with any value, will it override `$_SESSION['username']` and be a security issue ?

Comment: here before storing to session, `$username` value secured by real_escape. so no issues

Comment: You do not answer my question. I will try to reformulate. When calling `extract($_POST)` all variables inside the POST superglobal variable will be imported within the current scope. So if `$_POST['username']` is sent, `$username` will be accessible, following ? Then if a user succeeds to send `$_POST['_SESSION']` the variable `$_SESSION` would be exported the same way as `$username` ?

Comment: I got your point, but `$_POST['_SESSION']['username']` not effect the `$_SESSION["username"]`. Because session username is the latest updated value. also `$_SESSION["username"]` is a superglobal. so if you call `$_SESSION["username"]` it will be same as $username after escaped. I hope you understand. If you need I will give you an example.. or try your self and prove your statement. if you right i will agree with you. :)

Comment: I totally agree with you in the case where the user is authenticated (if statement). But if the user is not authenticated (else statement where the session is not updated), and if it tries to inject the `$_SESSION['username']`, it can "emulate" a valid connection. Would it be more "secure" not to use `extract()` but instead only get the variable with `$username = $_POST['username']`. I'm not an expert and do not know the behavior in this case, just wondering. Feel free to test it.

Comment: by the way, you are not validating the escape-string in your answer. update it :)

Comment: Didn't think of this issue with `extract()` before, I will then be more careful. Yes, thank you I totally forgot !